# japanese encoding issue, keeps reverting to turkish (windows)

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I have some php files which the text is outputting (in dreamweaver) as
 stuff like...

“–“ú‚Í‚±‚¿‚ç‚Ìƒ[ƒ‹‚ğˆóü‚µ‚Äó•t‚É‚Ä‚²’ñ¦‚­‚¾‚³‚¢B

It is supposed to be Japanese text, if I change the encoding in dreamweaver to swift-JIS, the text look like:

ƒxƒ‹ƒRƒ~ƒ…ƒjƒP[ƒVƒ‡ƒ“ƒYƒŠƒ~ƒeƒbƒh

So i open the file in notepad ++ and  character set to Japanese (swift-jis) and paste it back in to dreamweaver and then change the encoding and everything looks great.. I save, reopen and boom, back to turkish and the weird encoding. Any ideas?

On the actual website it looks OK, its just i want to be able to edit it in dream weaver and obviously come back to it in a later date and still be able to read it.

Comment: hi you may want to tag php and webdevelopment and remove the tags for japanese and shift-jis

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still interested: I found this answer smwhere on the web and it worked for me:
to explicitly say DW what encoding to use, manually place this line in the beginning of your page:

where xxxxxxx should be replaced with correct name for your encoding (see modify-page props.-document encoding for that).

Hope that helps. 
Peter-ta

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly tell Dreamweaver to open the file in Swift-JIS.

[Here](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe%3aChange_page_encoding_in_Dreamweaver_27468409) is a tutorial that seems to explain how. Maybe there also is a select box in the "Open" Dialog.

Comment: hi, this is what I do initially, however it does not encode correctly., So i have to convert it in notepad and paste it back in, I cant believe that I can not change the encoding and it remembers it :S